# Code doesn't find any products on website

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4wOJ.png)I wrote some code (a piece of them below) to scrape all products from shop's website but it doesnt find any products... i dont know what is wrong with this code. Can someone help me? I added screnn to show html (product-tile represent some product-box so I think that I should use this class to have necessary information)

```
while True:
    # if True:
    try:
        prod = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-tile")
        for el in prod:
            name = el.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").text
            price = el.find_element_by_class_name("price-normal").text
            product_list.append(x)
            x = [name, price]
            print(x)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the website where the products are listed or the HTML from the page?

Comment: I added screen to my question. I

Comment: I don't see a link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code see if it helps.

```
prod=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-tile.js-UA-product")))

for el in prod:
  name = el.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  price = el.find_element_by_class_name("price-normal").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Please use following imports.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Hmm still doesnt working , hmm maybe should \I change class "product-tile", but it contains all information and its unique class (when I try to find "product-tile" in HTML, the number is the same as number of products on one webpage)

Comment: I have added one more class name try that.If not work check if there any iframe available?

Comment: Which iframe? I dont understand.

Comment: Serach iframe above where your product-tile element present?